# How to match and retrieve specific Sub-document value from Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I search and retrieve only "Stats.item.id" from this collection who have greater than zero "Stats.item.p" value. I am also facing problem in unwinding this collection.

```
{ 
 "_id" : "8643", 
"Stats" : [  
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-02-01"), 
        "Stats" : {
            "item" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "4356"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "9963", 
                    "p" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

```
{ 
 "_id" : "8643",
 {
    "date" : ISODate("2014-02-01"), 
    "Stats" : {
        "item" : [
         {
                    "id" : "9963", 
                    "p" : NumberInt(1)
                }
 }
```

This is the output I expect. Can anyone help me write this aggregation? oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooooo oooooooooooo oooooooo

Answer (score 1):

Hope this aggregation query will work

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:'$Stats'},
{$unwind:'$Stats.Stats'},
{$unwind:'$Stats.Stats.item'},
{$match:{
    'Stats.Stats.item.p':{$gt:0}
}},
{$group:{
    _id:{
        date:'$Stats.date'
    },
    item:{$push:'$Stats.Stats.item'},
    _ids:'$_id'
}},
{$group:{
    _id:{_ids:'$_ids',
    date:'$_id.date'},
    Stats:{$push:{
        item:'$item'
        }},
}},
{$project:{
    _id:'$_id._ids',
    Stats:{
        date:'$_id.date'
        Stats:'$Stats'
    }
}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **$elemMAtch** for searching in the array.

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({
    "Stats": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "Stats.item": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "p": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: But it even returns all the unmatched subdocuments. Any other way to filter them?

Comment: for that, you have to use aggregate.